# How to add pagination in a list on a frontend view?

Tags: pagination, twig, octobercms

In octoberCMS, how do I paginate a list with hundreds of items and display pagination elements?

Comment: You can accept your own answer and then close this question.

Comment: In two days it says...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your component (this is like a controller) get all Users in chunks of 15 per page and pass them to your page view:

```
$users = User::paginate(15);
$this->page['users'] = $users;
```

In your view render a list and below the pagination-links (automatically!).

```
<div class="container">
    {% for user in users %}
        {{ user.name }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{{ users.render|raw }} // This renders pagination links
```